# Cannot figure out MySQL Access Denied User issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am utterly baffled. I've removed all passwords and other identifying information from the code snippets below.

Attempting to generate a "first login" row in a database, for future use logging in via website, using this:

```
<?php

include('mysqli.php');

$password = password_hash("REDACTED",PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('kaeden','" . $password . "','REDACTED')";

include('footer.php');

?>
```

mysqli.php is:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "pfs", "REDACTED", "pfs");

$mysqli -> connect();

?>
```

[image: PHPMyAdmin Users]
The footer.php simply closes the mysqli connection. I set up the user "pfs" with database-specific privilages for "pfs", and that didn't work. So I gave it full global access, still didn't work; I have copied and pasted the password to make sure I'm not typing it incorrectly, I've removed and re-added the user via phpmyadmin, and I'm utterly and completely baffled why all I get is:

[image: Error display]

I've spent 2 hours on this. What obvious thing am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that phpmyadmin and your php script are looking at the same mysql server??

Comment: I cannot fathom why they wouldn't be. Running latest version of Wampserver on Windows 11. I have other projects that work fine, I even copied/pasted the other project's mysqli.php and just altered the username/password/database. That's when the issues began, and I'm going around in circles.

Comment: Is PhpMyadmin definitely pointing to localhost - have you checked its config? And what port does it connect on? Do you by any chance also have MySQL and MariaDB both running the same machine? I've seen that be the cause in cases like this before.

Comment: So I discovered that Wampserver did have MariaDB running as well, I disabled it. I checked the port: 3306. Is there ANY process by which I can figure out exactly where it's failing?

Comment: UPDATE: I'm going to test this further, but I believe it was a database-specific permissions issue. If all my test cases work out correctly, I will put an answer here. Thank you for all the assistance, and I'll return if there are further issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had somehow messed up the permissions on the database that the connection was accessing. Without those permissions, it would not allow any connection at all, even with the proper username and password.

Double-check your database-specific permissions if you're experiencing the same issue.